# Thermodynamic stability

Tags: thermodynamics

Thermodynamically a gaseous state is more stable than a solid state for a given substance but according to minimum potential energy principle a solid should be more stable than gaseous state? I am unable to mark the difference regarding stability?

Comment: What does "stability" even mean in this context?

Comment: I meant to say the configuration with minimum potential energy

Comment: We observe that both solids and gasses exist in nature. What does this tell you?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/729698/226902

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gaseous state has a higher *entropy* than the solid state for a given substance, but we can't say that it's necessary more stable. The most stable equilibrium phase (for a given temperature $T$ and pressure $P$) is the one with the lowest Gibbs free energy $G=H-TS$, where $H$ is the enthalpy (representing the bonding strength, among other factors) and $S$ is the entropy (representing the number of available microstates for our given $T$ and $P$). At sufficiently low temperatures, the solid state is always more stable.